# NHibernate and LINQ - InvalidOperationException: "Could not find entity named ..."

Tags: linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

Have a look at the following tests:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CanRead()
{
    using (ISession session = OpenSession())
    {
        var criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Action));
        var result = criteria.List<Action>();
        Assert.IsTrue(result.Count > 0);
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void CanReadWithLinq()
{
    using (ISession session = OpenSession())
    {
        IEnumerable<Action> actionQuery = from action in session.Linq<Action>() 
                                          where action.CreatedOn < DateTime.Now
                                          select action;
        List<Action> actions = actionQuery.ToList();
        Assert.IsNotNull(actions);
        Assert.IsTrue(actions.Count > 0);
    }
}
```

First one runs, so I assume that the mapping is correct (using NHibernate.Attributes in the `Action` class). Test two fails with the exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException:
>   Could not find entity named:
>   BOM.Domain.Action.

It turns out, that every linq expression that uses the entity in the where condition fails with this exception. Removing the where will make it pass, but this is not what I want to achieve, of course. What am I missing? Why is there this exception?

---

### Update:

I created a separate project as follows.

The domain object:

```
namespace Domain
{
    public class TestEntity
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The mapping document:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class entity-name="T_TestEntity" name="Domain.TestEntity, Domain" lazy="false">
    <id name="Id" />
    <property name="CreatedOn" column="CreatedOn" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Unit test initialization creates a SQL CE database file, which looks to be fine. Tests are quite similar, and I've got the same behavior as before: The fetching with ICriteria works fine, the fetching with Linq works fine until I add a condition that is related to the domain object. Same InvalidOperationException as before, here the stack trace:

> Test method Tests.ReadTests.CanReadWithLinq threw
>   exception: 
>   System.InvalidOperationException:
>   Could not find entity named:
>   Domain.TestEntity. at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Util.CriteriaUtil.GetRootType(CriteriaImpl
>   criteria) at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Util.CriteriaUtil.GetRootType(ICriteria
>   criteria) at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.MemberNameVisitor.IsRootEntity(EntityExpression
>   expr) at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.MemberNameVisitor.VisitEntity(EntityExpression
>   expr) at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.NHibernateExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression
>   exp) at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.NHibernateExpressionVisitor.VisitPropertyAccess(PropertyAccessExpression
>   expr) at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.MemberNameVisitor.VisitPropertyAccess(PropertyAccessExpression
>   expr) at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.NHibernateExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression
>   exp) at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.MemberNameVisitor.GetMemberName(ICriteria
>   rootCriteria, Expression expr) at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.BinaryCriterionVisitor.VisitPropertyAccess(PropertyAccessExpression
>   expr) at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.NHibernateExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression
>   exp) at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.BinaryCriterionVisitor.GetBinaryCriteria(ICriteria
>   rootCriteria, ISession session,
>   BinaryExpression expr,
>   ComparePropToValue comparePropToValue,
>   ComparePropToProp comparePropToProp,
>   CompareValueToCriteria
>   compareValueToCriteria,
>   ComparePropToCriteria
>   comparePropToCriteria) at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.WhereArgumentsVisitor.VisitBinaryCriterionExpression(BinaryExpression
>   expr) at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.WhereArgumentsVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression
>   expr) at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression
>   exp) at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.NHibernateExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression
>   exp) at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ExpressionVisitor.VisitLambda(LambdaExpression
>   lambda) at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression
>   exp) at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.NHibernateExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression
>   exp) at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.WhereArgumentsVisitor.VisitUnary(UnaryExpression
>   expr) at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression
>   exp) at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.NHibernateExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression
>   exp) at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.WhereArgumentsVisitor.GetCriterion(ICriteria
>   rootCriteria, ISession session,
>   Expression expression) at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.RootVisitor.HandleWhereCall(MethodCallExpression
>   call) at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.RootVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression
>   expr) at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression
>   exp) at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.NHibernateExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression
>   exp) at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.NHibernateQueryTranslator.Translate(Expression
>   expression, QueryOptions queryOptions)
>   at
>   NHibernate.Linq.NHibernateQueryProvider.TranslateExpression(Expression
>   expression) at
>   NHibernate.Linq.NHibernateQueryProvider.Execute(Expression
>   expression) at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Query`1.GetEnumerator()
>   at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault<TSource>(IEnumerable`1
>   source) at
>   Tests.ReadTests.CanReadWithLinq() in
>   ReadTests.cs: line 52.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is not in the code you're showing... could you post more code?

Comment: Of course not. But I don't know what part of code should be posted without bloating the question to an unreadable state. I was hoping someone says "Ah, when everything is fine but only the Linq statements are crashing with InvalidOperationException you should check ..."

Comment: The funny thing: neither http://www.google.de/search?q="Could+not+find+entity+named"+linq has some results, nor http://www.google.de/search?q="Could+not+find+entity+named"+nhibernate - so the problem seems to be very obscure and rare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it after fetching the NHibernate and NHibernate Contrib sources and stepping through: I have to provide the entity name from the database when creating the INHibernateQueryable.

```
IEnumerable<TestEntity> query = from testEntity in session.Linq<TestEntity>("T_TestEntity") 
    where testEntity.CreatedOn < DateTime.Now
    select testEntity;
```

<strike>I'm still unsure if this is the final solution.</strike>

---

### Update

The mapping document defined the entity name instead of the table name. This resulted in a correct schema when exporting and it was also capable of handling the existing schema. However, it behaves different wwith Linq. The correct mapping definition would be:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class table="T_TestEntity" name="Domain.TestEntity, Domain">
    <id name="Id" />
    <property name="CreatedOn" column="CreatedOn" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

or (when using the attribute mapping of NHibernate Contrib):

```
[Class(Name = "Domain.TestEntity, Domain", Table = "T_TestEntity")]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a problem with the XML mapping file. Could you check your file Action.hbm.xml, do "F4" and set "Build Action" to "Embedded Resource".

Comment: This is not the problem. I am using NHibernate.Attributes and create the mapping document on thy fly. Moreover, if this would be the problem, the other test would not pass.
However, even when using the static mapping xml the same problem persists.